# How to retrieve detail of HTTP response error

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest

I've got a node.js application that is making some https requests to a ReST web service.
I want to do something that, on the face of it, appears like it should be simple - retrieve the error message that comes back from the web service.

I can get hold of the status code - i.e. 200, 404 etc but not the detail of the error.

The body of the response looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5",
    "title" : "Not Found",
    "status": "404",
    "detail": "Resource not found: X33003"
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "hostname": "myhost.com",
    "port": null,
    "path": "/mypath/",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "authorization": basicAuthString,
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
};

try {
     var reqWorkSkill = http.request(options, function(res) {
     var chunks = [];
     res.on("data", function(chunk) {
         chunks.push(chunk);
     });
     res.on("end", function() {
         var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);             
         var response = JSON.parse(body);
         console.log("Detail: " + body.detail);  // COMES BACK UNDEFINED
     });
     res.on("error", function(error) {         
         console.log("Something went wrong with: " + resourceIdArray[i] + " failed: " + error);
     });
     if(res.statusCode != 200){
         // Do some stuff
     }
     console.log("res status: " + res.statusCode);
     console.log("res text: " + res.statusText); // COMES BACK UNDEFINED

    });
    reqWorkSkill.write(itemToPost);                       
    reqWorkSkill.end();
} 
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

It would be useful to be able to present what exactly went wrong - i.e the message: Resource not found: X33003 from the JSON above.  How can I get hold of that?

Comment: Can we see the `options` object? Also, are you expecting binary data?

Comment: Hi ishegg - Updated to include the Options object.  The data returned isn't binary, there's either nothing returned with status of 200 or, I think, a body containing the JSON I included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just had the wrong properties of the objects you were calling. First, you were calling `body.detail`, but `body` was the `Buffer` representation. You need to call the `detail` property on `response`. Second, you were trying to get the `statusText`property of the response, but the correct property is `statusMessage`. Code ends up like this:

```
var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "hostname": "myhost.com",
    "port": null,
    "path": "/mypath/",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "authorization": basicAuthString,
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
};

try {
     var reqWorkSkill = http.request(options, function(res) {
     var chunks = [];
     res.on("data", function(chunk) {
         chunks.push(chunk);
     });
     res.on("end", function() {
         var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);             
         var response = JSON.parse(body);
         console.log("Detail: " + response.detail);  // response, not body
     });
     res.on("error", function(error) {         
         console.log("Something went wrong with: " + resourceIdArray[i] + " failed: " + error);
     });
     if(res.statusCode != 200){
         // Do some stuff
     }
     console.log("res status: " + res.statusCode);
     console.log("res text: " + res.statusMessage); // statusMessage, not statusText

    });
    reqWorkSkill.write(itemToPost);                       
    reqWorkSkill.end();
} 
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

It's always a good idea to `console.log` (or the equivalent) the object you're trying to access if you're not getting the correct results, that will show you all the properties of the object.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give that a go.  In terms of logging, absolutely - I've been wanting to do this.
I've tried logging (console and using log4js) but haven't found a useful way to get the properties to show.  I just see [object] printed.  Do you have a way to interrogate the object so that its properties are logged?

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log()` the `res` object? I get the full fledged object in the terminal.

Comment: I was incorrectly obsessing about the req object when it's res I need.  I can see the full contents of res.  Thanks again

Comment: Great! Happy to help.